# How do I concatenate two Lua luaL_Buffer ojbects?

Tags: c, api, lua, buffer, concatenation

Using the Lua C-API is there an efficient way to concatenate two `LuaL_Buffer`s?  I'd rather not do any unnecessary memcopys and want the result consumed by `luaL_pushresult()`.   The buffers contain embedded zeros so I can't convert them to char arrays and use `luaL_addstring()`.  It is acceptable to modify either buffer.

```
luaL_Buffer buf1;
luaL_Buffer buf2;
luaL_buffinit(L, &buf1);
luaL_buffinit(L, &buf2);  
luaL_addchar(&buf1, "a");
luaL_addchar(&buf2, "b");
luaL_addchar(&buf1, "\0");
luaL_addchar(&buf2, "\0");
luaL_pushresult(L, Want_this(&buf1, &buf2) ); // "a\0b\0" is now the Lua string 
                                              //  at the top of the stack
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could push `buf2` onto the stack first, add it to `buf1` (which pops it), then push `buf1` onto the stack.

```
luaL_pushresult(L, &buf2); // push "b\0" onto the stack
luaL_addvalue(&buf1); // pop that string and add it to buf1
luaL_pushresult(L, &buf1); // push "a\0b\0" onto the stack
```

Answer (score 2):

Create the whole string at C level instead and use `luaL_addlstring`, this way null character can be safely added to the buffer.